# Difference between the concepts of graph and trace

Tags: calculus, general-topology, differential-geometry, definition

I'm a little confused with the definition of graph and trace. If I have a function (or a curve) $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R,\ f(t)=t^2$ and I draw the graph we have a parabola since the graph is the ordered pairs of this form $(t,f(t))$ but what's the trace? the $\mathbb R$?

On the other hand, we can draw the trace of this function (or curve) $\alpha:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R^2$, $\alpha (t)=(t,t^2)$ which has the same drawing the graph of $f$ and because of this fact is there some relation between $f$ and $\alpha$? Concerning the graph of $\alpha$, can we say it is $(t^2,t^3,\alpha(t))$?

I wrote anything wrong? I would be grateful if someone can help me with my doubts.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How's trace defined in that context?

Comment: @MichaelHoppe it's the image of the curve

Comment: For function $f:\Bbb R^m\to \Bbb R^n$ we have trace of $f$ is in $\Bbb R^n$ graph of $f$ is in $\Bbb R^{m+n}$. Did you need this?

Answer (score 3):

Consider $\alpha(t)=(t,t^2) $with $t\in\boldsymbol{R}_+$ and $\beta(t)=\bigl(\exp(t),\exp(2t)\bigr)$ for $t\in\boldsymbol R$.  The traces are the same, but $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are different paths: the velocity vectors are different, for example.

Edit (an even more simple example): the traces of $t\mapsto t(1,0)$ and $t\mapsto t(-1,0)$ for $t\in\boldsymbol R$ are the same, namely the first coordinate axis. But the paths are obviously different.

Comment: What is the trace of $f(t)=t^2$ above? the real line?

Comment: @user42912 I don't quite understand your question.

Comment: If we draw the trace of $\alpha$ in your example, we have a parabola. I'm asking what looks like the drawing of the trace of $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$, $f(t)=t^2$.

Comment: @user42912 Not quite: the traces of $\alpha$ and $\beta$  are the same, namely $\{(x,x^2)\mid x>0\}$.  Please note that $x>0$.

Comment: yes, of course, my mistake.

Comment: I have a doubt concerning the terminology, we can say that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are the same curve with different parametrization? I think I have already heard this notation somewhere and this gave me some confusion.

Comment: They are two different curves but every point of $\alpha$ isa point of $\beta$.  They differ by a parametrization.  Do you see the difference of the more simple example in my answer?

Comment: yes, I understood very well, thank you for the explanations.

Comment: Dear Michael concerning the graph of $\alpha$, can we say it is $(t^2,t^3,\alpha(t))$?

Comment: No, because your path is clearly in $\boldsymbol R^4$.

Comment: Sorry, the graph of $\alpha$ is $(t,\alpha(t))$, right?